# Время анимации CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

Нужно в зависимости от расположения мыши изменять скорость анимации. Пока есть 7 элементов:

```
<div class="main-body">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```

Вот для них стили:

```
.main-body .photo{
    width: 300px;
    height: 430px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 450px;
    background: url('1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition-duration: 3s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
    transform: scale(1,1);
    z-index: 3;
}

.photo:nth-child(1),
.photo:nth-child(2){
    z-index: 1;
    left: 39px;
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
}
.photo:nth-child(1){z-index: 0;}

.photo:nth-child(3){
    transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    left: 234px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.photo:nth-child(5){
    transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    left: 696px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.photo:nth-child(6),
.photo:nth-child(7){
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    z-index: 1;
    left: 942px;
}
.photo:nth-child(7){z-index: 0;}
```

С помощью JavaScript попытался изменить время анимации:

```
k = 1;
photo_items = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
hidden = document.getElementById('super-hidden');
body = document.getElementsByClassName('main-body')[0];
body.onmousemove = function(event){
    var tmp = event.pageX-body.getBoundingClientRect().left-body.getBoundingClientRect().width/2;
    if (tmp > 0) changeTime(tmp*100);
}
hidden.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName('photo')[6].cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementsByClassName('main-body')[0].appendChild(tmp);
    document.getElementsByClassName('photo')[0].remove();
    photo_items = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
    k++;
    hidden.style.left = (10 + 10 * (k % 2 - 1)) + 'px';
});
start = function(){
    var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName('photo')[6].cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementsByClassName('main-body')[0].appendChild(tmp);
    document.getElementsByClassName('photo')[0].remove();
    photo_items = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
    hidden.style.left = (10 + 10 * (k % 2 - 1)) + 'px';
}

changeTime = function(v){
    for (var i = 0; i < photo_items.length; i++)
        photo_items[i].style.transitionDuration = v + 'ms';
    hidden.style.transitionDuration = v + 'ms';
}
```

Но скорость изменяется не во время наведения, а после того, как пройдет такт анимации. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

> Но скорость изменяется не во время наведения, а после того, как пройдет такт анимации. Как это исправить?

Это потому, что событий при движения мыши - примерно 50 штук в секунду, а у тебя стоит свойство transition-duration: 3s. То есть, этот бедный элемент, в 1/50 секунды всё хочет начать свой транзишн делать, но наступает 2/50 секунды - и он снова на старте пытается начать транзишн. И так далее - новые события его сбрасывают в начало.
Отменяй css-транзишн вообще, и меняй положение элемента, задавая его из JS.
По-моему путь такой, тем более, что js-анимации сейчас очень шустрые, если сделать через

**requestAnimationFrame**

https://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation